# A random sample of 15 adults was drawn. Determine the probability that 5 or less have a below average IQ.

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

A random sample of 15 adults was drawn. Determine the probability that 5 or less have a below average IQ. N(100,16)

Comment: It would be helpful if you include your work and clearly indicate where you are stuck. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: This raises another question : Imagine that the person who is going to answer you has a below-the-average IQ : will you be confident in his/her answer ?

Comment: More seriously, why don't you answer to @Max about your work on the subject, and the result you propose ?

Comment: I have done a little simulation on Matlab. The result I find is $\approx 0.151$. Wish it helps you to check your result found by a more classical way...

Answer (score 0):

You have the mean and the standard deviation, you can find the probability of any event happening in your space of events, here mean is 100 and standard deviation is 16,this is a statistic problem.
https://www.math.stackexchange.com/questions/482530/given-mean-and-standard-deviation-find-the-probability

you may want to search for **Chebyshev's inequality**.